# How can I get this DateTime format in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-4.0

I'm trying to format some DateTime into this [W3C DateTime format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) :-

```
Complete date plus hours and minutes:
eg. YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00)

where:
 YYYY = four-digit year
 MM   = two-digit month (01=January, etc.)
 DD   = two-digit day of month (01 through 31)
 hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)
 mm   = two digits of minute (00 through 59)
 ss   = two digits of second (00 through 59)
 s    = one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second
 TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)
```

I originally had this...

```
var myDateTime = someDateTime.ToString("s",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But that results in a string of :

```
2011-08-31T08:46:00
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following:

```
yourDateTime.ToString( "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
```

Here is more than you'll ever want to know on DateTime formats:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: `hh` is the 12 hour clock - and the OP should also use the invariant culture to make sure that `-` doesn't get replaced with `/` etc.

Answer (score 5):

You want [`"o"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#Roundtrip):

```
var myDateTime = someDateTime.ToString("o",
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: ?? So "o" is the same as "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmK" ?

Comment: Quote from MSDN: "The pattern for this specifier reflects a defined standard (ISO 8601)." ... and the WC3 page: "The International Standard for the representation of dates and times is ISO 8601. Its full reference number is ISO 8601 : 1988 (E),"  ... I think we have a winner :)

Comment: It is the same as "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffK"

Comment: You need to create a "DateTimeOffset" to get the time zone difference included (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip).

Comment: @Michael: That's not correct. Every datetime object that is `Local` contains the offset and ToString will respect that. `DateTime.Now.ToString("o")` gives `2011-09-02T12:30:05.6079843+02:00` on my machine. I am in Germany with DST, i.e. UTC+2

Comment: @Daniel: This will include seconds and fractions of seconds, which doesn't look like the original specification.

Comment: @Jon: I am not so sure. He quotes from the W3C page which indeed allows seconds and fractions of a second. He even posted them in his question: "ss   = two digits of second (00 through 59);s    = one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second"

Comment: @Daniel: No, the DateTime value itself doesn't contain the offset - it assumes that it's local to the time zone of the local machine.

Comment: @Daniel: He quotes from the W3C page which lists several formats, but in the question he's specified one that *doesn't* include seconds.

Comment: @Daniel: Apologies, MSDN implied that this wasn't the case

Comment: @Jon: You are right. My comment was worded badly. Still `DateTimeOffset` only makes sense, if you need a timezone different from that of the local machine.

Comment: @Jon: I know - because of the reasons outlined above I saw this as a lapse in the question. If he really doesn't want the seconds, he can still go with your answer. Just let the OP decide.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want

```
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmK"
```

Note:

- HH rather than hh to be 24 hour
- K to specify the time zone; this relies on the `DateTime.Kind` being UTC or local; unspecified will end up with an empty string

You should *also* use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to make sure no funky culture information is used. (You could quote the `-` and `:` as an alternative, but I'd use the invariant culture to make sure.)

Answer (score 1):

You can format it like this:

```
someDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Here's the documentation of the 'standard' supported datetime format strings:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Sorry. i displayed the wrong line.. Topic updated.. (needs to include hours mins and the timezone?)

Answer (score 0):

```
someDateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("u");
```

Will get you pretty close => '2011-09-02 10:22:48Z'. If that isn't good enough, then you can create a custom format string that includes the "T" (see ['Custom Date and Time Format Strings'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)).