# How to convert "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD" to yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

When I run this in C# in .net452,

```
DateTime myDateTime = Convert.TodateTime("2019-10-22T14:32:54.67685+01:00")
```

on my rig I get eg 22/10/2019 14:32:54, but on my client pc, I'm seeing "2019-10-27 01:32:54".

How do I convert that string to a local date time on the PC?

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281995/how-can-i-get-this-datetime-format-in-net) tells you how to convert to that format, but I need the reverse.

Pointers please!

Comment: Is it as simple as 
myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime("2019-10-22T14:32:54.67685+01:00").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));

Comment: `DateTimeOffset.Parse("2019-10-22T14:32:54.67685+01:00").ToLocalTime().DateTime`. I recommend leaving `Convert` out of it where possible; its rules for various types are not at all intuitive. (And while `DateTime.Parse` does actually accept time zones, being explicit about expecting one is cleaner.)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply @Jeroen.., just to confirm that it should be working as  expected, if I pass in "2019-10-23T13:34:14.352486+00:00" then the answer is "23/10/2019 14:34:14" and it it were +01:00, it would be "23/10/2019 13:34:14"??  As you can see, DateTime stuff really hacks me off!

Comment: Well it's unclear what, precisely, you're after. `DateTime` counts time in ticks and contains no time zone information, so converting always yields the same result on every machine in *absolute* terms (same number of ticks). How that (time-zone- less) `DateTime` then gets *displayed* is another matter. It sounds like you're seeing 01:32 when you expected 13:32, which seems to indicate that one machine uses a 12-hour clock for display and the other a 24-hour clock. If *that's* your problem rather than time zones you need to format it unambiguously (per the answer).

Comment: @Jeroen.  Thanks for the info re DateTime and ticks - I didn't know that!  Basically the problem is that I am processing an XML file which has a date eg "2019-10-22T14:32:54.67685+01:00".  In code, I have DateTime myDate = Convert.DateTime(that-time-string) and then later on I write that date to a postgres db field (of type "Timestamp Time zone").  On my rig, all is well, and the dates are fine but on a client machine, I noticed that the dates were in the future...   So basically, I want to read a string that contains a date, process it and store it (and obviously, do the reverse).

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to format the date .

```
Convert.ToDateTime("12/02/21 10:56:09").ToString("MMM.dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Use DateTime.ParseExact, e.g.:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("12/02/21 10:56:09", "yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    ).ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```